# I'm using 2 submit buttons in a single form

Tags: python, html, django

HTML page:

```
<form method="get" action="#">
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
<th>Slno</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Attendance</th> 
    </tr>
  <tr>
<td>1</td>
    <td>Abijith</td>
    <td>{{ p }}
<input type="submit"  value="present" name="add"/>
<input type="submit" value="absent" name="add1"/>
{{ a }}
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Views.py:

```
p = 1; a = 1;
def Ist_std(request):
    global p,a
my_dictionary = {
        "p" : p, "a" : a
}
if request.GET.get('add'):
        p = p+1
        my_dictionary = {
            "p" : p,
        }
    if request.GET.get('add1'):
        a = a+1
        my_dictionary = {
            "a" : a,
        }
return render(request, "blog/Ist_std.html", my_dictionary)
```

I want to show the value on the screen. But now I can see the values of `{{ p }}` and `{{ a }}` only when I click on the button. How can I show the values without clicking?

Comment: It's not the problem, but you should never, ever use global variables for things like this; they're not thread safe and will persist across requests from different users.

Comment: The title of your question should say something about the actual problem.